# Find rows with large time difference and copy those rows to new column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file like below:

```
{"ts": "01/03/2018 15:48:09+0530", "userid": "user1", "eventid":"EnterTripDetail" }
{"ts": "01/03/2018 15:48:09+0530", "userid": "user2", "eventid":"EnterTripDetail" }
{"ts": "01/03/2018 15:48:10+0530", "userid": "user1", "eventid":"ClickToPayTrip" }
{"ts": "01/03/2018 15:48:10+0530", "userid": "user2", "eventid":"ClickToPayTrip" }
{"ts": "01/03/2018 15:48:11+0530", "userid": "user1", "eventid":"SubmitPayment" }
```

Current code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("/examples/transaction.json");
df.show();
```

Now I want to know the list of users who have not completed the payments within 10 minutes, in my case I want to know the users whose time between `ClickToPayTrip` and `SubmitPayment` is more than 10 minutes or if there is no `SubmitPayment` entry of a user.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, can a user have more than one event of each?

Comment: No, no user will not have more than one entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicks and submits can be split into different dataframes, then joined by left join, and filtered to only have users with no payments or late payments left:

```
// get clicks and payments
Dataset<Row> clickToPayTripDF = df.where(col("eventid").equalTo("ClickToPayTrip"));
Dataset<Row> submitPaymentDF = df.where(col("eventid").equalTo("SubmitPayment"));

// join
Dataset<Row> joined = clickToPayTripDF.alias("click")
    .join(submitPaymentDF.alias("payment"), clickToPayTripDF.col("userid").equalTo(submitPaymentDF.col("userid")), "left");
// filter
Dataset<Row> result = joined
    .withColumn("clickSeconds", to_timestamp(col("click.ts"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").cast("long"))
    .withColumn("paymentSeconds", to_timestamp(col("payment.ts"), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").cast("long"))
    .where(
        col("payment.eventid").isNull().or(
            expr("paymentSeconds-clickSeconds > 600")
        ))
    .drop("clickSeconds", "paymentSeconds")
    .select("click.userid", "click.ts", "click.eventid");

result.show(false);
```

Output:

```
+------+------------------------+--------------+
|userid|ts                      |eventid       |
+------+------------------------+--------------+
|user2 |01/03/2018 15:48:10+0530|ClickToPayTrip|
+------+------------------------+--------------+
```